# Jboss JNDI name not found in hibernate configuration with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, jndi

I recently migrated from Struts 1.2 to Spring MVC. I am trying to deploy ear in Jboss 7.1.1, and starting application from Scratch instead of using Action classes from Struts. I am using Hibernate as ORM tool for application.

Earlier in Struts application, JNDI datasource lookup by hibernate configuration was no issue. But for some reason, the same configuration does not seem to work with Spring. I am getting following error again and again:

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/oraclePool -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.ExecEngine."ExecEngine.war".env.oraclePool

The datasource in Jboss is configured in following way:

<datasource jndi-name="java:/oraclePool" pool-name="oraclePool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true"> ........ 
</datasource>

And hibernate configuration being used in hibernate.cfg.xml is:

<property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/oraclePool</property>

The name of the ear which I am trying to deploy is ExecEngine.ear having war and jar with the same name. The structure of this ear is:

- META-INF folder having MANIFEST.MF and application.xml
- lib folder
- ExecEngine.jar
- ExecEngine.war having WEB-INF folder which contains spring-servlet.xml and web.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to remove the comp/env from hibernate.cfg.xml ?

Comment: I modified jndi to java:/oraclePool in spring-servlet.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml. And it worked. Thanks.